# Record called functions during the transaction execution

Tags: contract-invocation, internal-transactions

I am analyzing the flash loan workflow.

Notice that PeckShield publishes an analyze report about bzx flash loan. See https://peckshield.medium.com/bzx-hack-full-disclosure-with-detailed-profit-analysis-e6b1fa9b18fc

[image]

I am curious which software or platform can be used to generated the called function list like this picture.

Thanks!

Comment: those are internal transactions, very complicated thing to get tracked